# jQuery: get JSON via ajax, but with POST instead of GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax to make a request to a third-party server, using JSONP.  I specify the method as POST, but it uses GET anyway:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: other_server + "/run?callback=?",
        data: {
            code: $(code).val()
        },
        success: function(obj) {
            var res = obj.results;
            $(results).val(res);
        }
    });
```

Looking in the jQuery source, I see these two lines that seem to force all cross-domain requests to GET, but I don't understand why it needs to be so:

```
if ( s.crossDomain ) {
    s.type = "GET";
```

Is it possible to do this with a POST instead of a GET?  Why does jQuery force the use of GET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON-P works by inserting a `<script>` element into the document, hence it can only make GET requests.

If you want to make a POST request to a remote server then you need to look at XHR instead and set up [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) permissions. Note that this has [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors).

Alternatively, keep your requests to the same origin (and have your server make the request to the remote server).

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense!